# Windows group membership doesn't work with "BUILTIN\Power Users"

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, permissions, file-permissions

This question came originally from a named pipe security issue when a member of the "BUILTIN\Power Users" group wasn't able to connect to the pipeline, even though the group was allowed to.

I made the following simple test to prove the concept:

1. Create a file and allow access to the file only for "BUILTIN\Administrators" and "BUILTIN\Power Users".
2. Make sure a non-admin user is in the "BUILTIN\Power Users" group.
3. The user IS NOT allowed to modify the file even though it has to be. Even after computer restart=)
4. If a "BUILTIN\Users" or any other custom group is used to allow access, it works as it should.

This test has been reproduced on different computers with Windows 10.

Can anyone explain if there's anything really special about the "BUILTIN\Power Users" group, so it cannot be used as a normal Windows group to restrict access with group membership?

I know that the "Power Users" concept is deprecated and the group was just left for compatibility, but, still, does it make it any different?

Answer (score 0):

The first step was to depreciate Power Users (and rename Limited Users to Users). The next step was to remove it. It no longer has any power at all. **It has no security privileges** (have a look in Secpol.msc - Local Security Policy - User Rights Assignments).

Power Users had enough power to make themselves Administrators.

> Windows administration​[edit]
>
> In Microsoft Windows 2000, Windows XP Professional, and Windows Server
> 2003, there is a "Power Users" group on the system that gives more
> permissions than a normal restricted user, but stops short of
> Administrator permissions. If a user is a member of the Power Users
> group, they have a greater chance of exposing the system to malware
> over a normal user and can promote their account to an Administrator
> by purposely installing malware.[12] Thus, the Power Users group
> should be used with trustworthy and knowledgeable users only; it is
> not suitable to contain untrustworthy users. The Power Users group was
> made obsolete in Windows Vista as part of the consolidation of
> privilege elevation features in the introduction of User Account
> Control.[13] In Windows Vista Business l or higher, you can still
> create a "power user" via local users and groups, but there is **no
> difference from a standard user because all the ACL entries of the
> file system are completely removed**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_user

Comment: > **all the ACL entries of the file system are completely removed**
- I know, it's clear, but what prevents creating new ACL entries and using the group just like a normal custom group?

Comment: **It has no security privileges**

Comment: I perfectly understand that it has no security privileges. The question is why I can't create any new privileges for this group.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?